# What is the word for the auto-technique humans use to find out whether a person is male or a female human being by their facial appearance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What is the word for auto-technique humans use to find out in a face to face encounter whether a person is male or a female human being by their facial appearance or body shape (masculine and feminine features/cues to make the distinction between males and females).

Elaboration: Such as female cheeks tend to be more prominent than male cheeks which may appear more angular and sharper the more the younger. Even featured lips, forehead, chin, nose, jaw, cheekbones, skin, and eyes distinguish the difference.

Comment: I would call it "Pategorization".

Comment: **Unreliable**.

Comment: @Cascabel This study identifies several features that are independent of culture (such as hair style or clothing) and concludes that adults can identify males vs. female faces 97+ percent of the time.

Comment: https://bbs.utdallas.edu/files/JECPWildFaceCategorization.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OED:

> **physiognomy,** n.
>
> **I. The study of appearance.**
>
> **1. a. The study of the features of the face, or of the form of the body generally, as being supposedly indicative of character; the art of judging character from such study.**
>
> 1853   C. Brontë Villette I. vii. 125   *I want your opinion. We know your skill in physiognomy... Read that countenance.*
>
> 1915   W. S. Maugham Of Human Bondage xxvi. 107   *Fräulein Anna took an interest in physiognomy and she made Philip notice afterwards how finely shaped was his skull, and how weak was the lower part of his face.*

Answer (score 1):

The general term used in research on the subject is **recognition**, which is modified to specify the kind of recognition performed: **facial recognition**, **gender recognition** (with context used to make clear that they are talking about faces), and **facial gender recognition**. Here are several examples from titles of articles:

- [A Review of **Facial Gender Recognition**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10044-015-0499-6)
- [**Facial Gender Recognition** Using Multiple Sources of Visual Information](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4665181/)
- [**Gender Recognition** of Human Faces Using Color](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9280.2008.02232.x)
- [**Facial Gender Recognition** Using Eyes Images](https://www.academia.edu/download/31994874/43-Hadeel_Alrashed_-facial_gender_recognition_using_eyes_images.pdf)

In some articles, *categorization* or *classification* are used alongside recognition, like in Wild et al., "[**Recognition and Sex Categorization** of Adults' and Children's Faces: Examining Performance in the Absence of Sex-Stereotyped Cues](https://bbs.utdallas.edu/files/JECPWildFaceCategorization.pdf)," *Journal of Experimental Child Psychology 77 (2000).

While [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sex%20recognition%2Cgender%20recognition%2Csex%20categorization%2Cgender%20categorization&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csex%20recognition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgender%20recognition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csex%20categorization%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgender%20categorization%3B%2Cc0) should be taken with a grain of salt, the illustration below shows that *gender recognition* outpaces near alternatives (*sex recognition, gender categorization, sex categorization*):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Phenotypic analysis**, is the scientific term for analysing the physical characteristics of a human or non-human being and reaching a conclusion about their gender, among other things.  Nowadays, however, appearances are often deceptive.

> - [**phenotype**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wHE0irTzD1QC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=%22A+phenotype+is+the+observable+expression+of+an+individual%27s+genotype.+Thus,%22&source=bl&ots=1omRCp9cZ3&sig=ACfU3U3GN3GmpnYgMmv3kRvqKyL4vLT06Q&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBmqqahODuAhU2GrkGHeoIANEQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22A%20phenotype%20is%20the%20observable%20expression%20of%20an%20individual%27s%20genotype.%20Thus%2C%22&f=false) *definition* - "A phenotype is the observable expression of an individual's genotype. Thus, while genotypes affect proteins, cells, and biological pathways, phenotypes are most readily observed as appearances."

> - "A [**phenotype**](https://sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/phenotype) is defined as an observable trait, either directly visible, such as hair color or presence of a disease."